# Why does VirtualBox (Windows 10) screen go black when it is in fullscreen mode on an Arch Linux host?

Tags: virtualbox, arch-linux, wayland

I'm trying to get VirtualBox working on my laptop and have already set up a Windows 10 virtual machine. Everything seems to be working fine in the default view:

[image]

However when I switch to fullscreen mode I get a black screen:

[image]

I'm running VirtualBox under Arch Linux/Hyprland (a Wayland Window Manager). Any ideas as to what might be causing this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: Just to confirm, do you have guest extensions installed in the VM?

Comment: @squillman Yes, I've installed the guest extensions from the iso in the VM.

Comment: Have you got the most up to date Host Video Driver?

Comment: @John I do; I'm using Intel graphics.

Comment: I am not sure. I do not have Arch Linux, I do not use VBOX, and I do not use full screen.  Two options:   (1) Try a different Virtual Machine (Ubuntu).  (2) Try a trial version of VMware Workstation. I use this and it works fine:  Ubuntu, Kali and Windows.

Comment: @John The only reason I'm using VB is for Windows but I'll give VMware WS a try.